# return value of function to another function python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, return

Disclaimer: I am new to programming.
The following code doesn't work, as it seems the output of function 1 is not passed to function 2.

```
def img_to_color(path_file):

# takes an image and calculates avg red / green / blue value
color_avg = [red, green, blue]
return color_avg        

def extract_RGB(path_folder):

j = 0
RGB = []
file_count = len(os.listdir(path_folder))
files = os.listdir(path_folder)
while j < file_count:
    img_to_color(path_folder + "/" + files[j])
    RGB.append(color_avg)
    j = j+1
X_training.append(trainingDataFolder(pfad, RGB))
```

The function img_to_color works, however RGB stays [] even though I call the function.

Comment: What is `X_training`? where it is declared? same goes for `red`, `green` and `blue`.

Comment: I excluded the calculation of red, green, blue to make it shorter. This function works fine. X_training also exists (declared outside as global).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `color_avg` is local to your `img_to_color` function. It does not exist inside of `extract_RGB`. `img_to_color` returns a value, so you have to either assign a variable to it like:

`color_avg = img_to_color(...)`

or directly pass the return value to a function like:

`RGB.append(img_to_color(...)`

Comment: Thank you very much Spencer.
Works perfectly like that and I finally understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the indentation. You should read [this](http://www.davekuhlman.org/python_101.html#blocks-and-indentation) first.

**BTW, the variable `X_training` doesn't seem to be declared anywhere, so I wasn't sure if it's part of more global context or not.**

The code should be written like this:

```
def img_to_color(path_file):
    # takes an image and calculates avg red / green / blue value
    color_avg = [red, green, blue]
    return color_avg        

def extract_RGB(path_folder):
    j = 0
    RGB = []
    file_count = len(os.listdir(path_folder))
    files = os.listdir(path_folder)
    while j < file_count:
        color_avg = img_to_color(path_folder + "/" + files[j])
        RGB.append(color_avg)
        j = j+1
    X_training.append(trainingDataFolder(pfad, RGB))
```